# How is the probability density for the deflection angle calculated from the differential cross-section?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

In a scattering process, the probability density for the deflection angle of the incident particle is proportional to the differential cross-section of that scattering process. Given the differential cross-section, how is the probability density for the deflection angle of the particle calculated?

For example, the differential cross-section for a Moller scattering process (collision of two electrons) is given in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Møller_scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8ller_scattering) (end of the article). What would be the probability that the electron is deflected by an angle between θ and 90 degrees, after colliding another electron?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that
$$
p(x) \propto \frac{d\sigma}{dx}
$$
from which it is easy to find
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma} \frac{d\sigma}{dx}
$$
which follows from $\int p(dx) dx = 1$.

Comment: is dσ/dx the differential cross section here? What are σ and x?

Comment: it;s the differential cross section with respect to some variable $x$. The $x$ should be some information about the phase space of the final state particles. In your case, you would probably want $x \to \theta$, the angle between outgoing electron and beam axis (in com frame)

Answer (score 1):

A probability density can be obtained by integrating the differential cross section over $d\Omega$.

For Moller scattering we have
$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}
=\frac{\alpha^2}{8E^2}
\left(
\frac{1+\cos^4(\theta/2)}{\sin^4(\theta/2)}
+\frac{8}{\sin^2\theta}
+\frac{1+\sin^4(\theta/2)}{\cos^4(\theta/2)}
\right)
$$

Let
$$
I(\xi)=2\pi\int_\alpha^\xi\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\,\sin\theta\,d\theta,
\quad\alpha\le\xi\le\pi-\alpha
$$

for some $\alpha>0$.
The support range is restricted because $d\sigma$ is undefined at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$.

The cumulative distribution function is
$$
F(\theta)=\frac{I(\theta)}{I(\pi-\alpha)},
\quad\alpha\le\theta\le\pi-\alpha
$$

The probability density is
$$
f(\theta)=\frac{dF(\theta)}{d\theta}
=\frac{2\pi}{I(\pi-\alpha)}
\left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\right)
\sin\theta,
\quad\alpha\le\theta\le\pi-\alpha
$$

Here is a graph of $f(\theta)$ for $\alpha=\pi/180$.

[image: ?]

Comment: See http://eigenmath.org/moller-scattering.pdf for more.